# Windows batch dynamic URL script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Is there a possibility to set Website URL in dynamic way and open it with batch script? (by using e.g. start chrome "-URL here-")

Example.
I have a link with an excel file, which I want to download: 
www.example.com/example_15/example_123.xlsx

and each day specific part of URL is changing, e.g. tomorrow it could be:
www.example.com/example_12/example_abc1.xlsx

Is there any way how I can replace changing parts of the URL so it would always download an excel file ?

Comment: And how the client could know what the link will be? Is there some kind of request to the server that will give this information?

Comment: Unfortunately, it cannot be predictable... thus I was thinking, is it possible to have something like using  " *  "  to replace this changing part?

Comment: this depends on the server (e.g. apache server has plugins that will emulate a file system and will show you the files and folders with their modification dates). you can check also spider capabilities of WGET tool , but there's no simple way to do this.